# BeanUtils.copyProperties and nested List

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to convert an object to another one, and for that I use Spring BeanUtils. But a property 'foo' of type `Bag<X>` (issued from Hibernate) is copied in the target object of type `List<Y>` without problem.

The corresponding setter is used : `setFoo(List<Y> foo)` and in debug mode I see that 'foo' is of type `Bag<X>`.

Edit: example

```
class Foo {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{add(1);}};

    public List<Integer> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<Integer> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}

class Bar {
    List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>() {{add(1.0);}};

    public List<Double> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<Double> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

Then :

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Bar bar = new Bar();
Bar bar2 = new Bar();
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.copyProperties(foo, bar);
org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties(foo, bar2);
```

Result : bar.getList() is a List of Double (no modification) and bar2.getList() is a List of Integer (property copied from source to target).

Why no ClassCastException is thrown ?
How can Spring set this property ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, As you can see in this [link](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-2/api/net/sf/hibernate/collection/Bag.html)

```
public class Bag
extends ODMGCollection
implements org.odmg.DBag, List
```

Bag implements List.

Comment: Ok, List and Bag is the same type, but what about nested type X => Y ?
See example in my edited question.